# last dynamically appended content missing from post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending a block with jQuery dynamically but when I post the form, the last appended block is not getting posted?

my problem is when the last block is appended with loop...it post all other blocks but not read the last one...for example if 5 block is added but it posts only till fourth block.

here is my some of code

```
limit =  $("#conditions1").find('option').length-2;    
if( limit >= counter ) {        
            counter++;
            var a = $("#dynamic").html();
            var cond = "conditions"+counter;
            var cond_val = "conditions_value"+counter;
            var cond_no = "Condition"+counter;
            var tr1 = "tr_first"+counter;
            var tr2 = "tr_second"+counter;
            var sub_cond_val = "sub_conditions_value"+counter;

            $("#dynamic_id").html(a);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#condition_no').text(cond_no);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#tr_first').attr('id',tr1);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#tr_second').attr('id',tr2);


            $("#dynamic_id").find('#conditions').attr('name',cond);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#conditions').attr('id',cond);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#conditions_value').attr('name',cond_val);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#conditions_value').attr('id',cond_val);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#sub_conditions_value').attr('name',sub_cond_val);
            $("#dynamic_id").find('#sub_conditions_value').attr('id',sub_cond_val);

            var b = $("#dynamic_id").html();
            $("#dynamic_conditions").append(b);
            $("#dynamic_conditions").show();
```

Comment: There seems to be some parts missing from the question. I cannot se that you add any input fields and no form example. Where does the #dynamic and #dynamic_id come from?

Comment: i am taking the id's of the <tbody> in which i am appending all this..i have no  problem regarding appending it's all working..but when i post the form after selecting all the values(input types are only dropdown box)....it doesn't post the last clicked or appended block....wether i click one time or 10 times ...it is not posting the last clicked...

Comment: How are you posting, is that a separate operation or is it done within the add loop? Can you check generated source before posting to verify that the input fields are in place.

Comment: i am simply posting and getting the values $_POST[] method of php when he selects all the fields..

Comment: Try to get hold over the generated source before posting so that you can verify that the fields are there with the correct names. If the fields are present they should be included. If they are not then there should be something wrong in the source. Firefox + Firebug can show generated source, also IE debugbar has the same features.

Comment: hi :) i have solved my problem....all i have to do is this $("#dynamic_id").empty(); after appending it to where i want...anyways thanks for concern :)

Comment: Write this as your own solution and accept so that other see that it is answered and done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello if anybody is looking for this type of problem..then answer is

The block(say a) which with you are appending in the other block(say b) you should empty that "a" block again after appending that "b" block ....you can that by $("#a").empty()

Comment: Flag this as the accepted answer to. It first indicates to others that the problem is solved so that helpful people do not waste time trying to solve already solved problems. It also helps those looking for a solution to find the questions that most likely contain a solution, not just more questions. And Finally, getting your accepted rate up will make it more likely that future questions you have will get fast answers.